# How to upload a local file under a different name with the node client library?

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud's python client library interface allows you to specify a remote blob name (i.e., `/my/file.txt` -> `gs://bucket/newName.txt`). However, I do not see a way to do this in the node client library.

I've got the example working in python but I was relying on being able to prepend filenames on the storage server with a timestamp. This presents an issue as (AFAIK) the node library simply uses the local file name.

[Python example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) - has source/destination names

```py
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

[Node example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) - uses local filename

```
// Uploads a local file to the bucket
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
  // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
    // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
    // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
  },
});
```

Is there any way to specify what the uploaded filename is with the node client library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the node SDK, you can specify a destination file in the options object you pass as the second object to upload.  There is an example in the [API docs for upload()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#upload).

```
storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(localFilePath, {
    destination: remoteFilePath
})
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for!